# GWT 2.8 with Classic Dev Mode error when I use @JsType | @JsMethod sample

Tags: java, gwt

my framework project has a EJB architecture design with client GWT2.7 + gwt-material 1.6 and smartGWT for some widgets over maven model, also I use Classic Dev Mode (the best for me) tool for debug and I haven't had any problem with this, until today...

When I upgraded GWT2.7 to 2.8 I wrote a @JsType example, I get the next error:

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null) @com.mypackage.MyApplication$SomeClassJsType::getName()([]): null

Here is the class:

```
@JsType(isNative=true, namespace = "com.cnames")
public class SomeClassJsType {
    @JsMethod
    public static native String getName();
}
```

Here is how I used that class in EntryPoint

```
rootPanel.add( new Label( SomeClassJsType.getName() ) );
```

And here is the javascript fragment in HTML page

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        com = { cnames: {} };
        com.cnames.SomeClassJsType = function () {
                this.name = "hello";    
        };
        com.cnames.SomeClassJsType.getName = function () {
                this.name = "world";    
        };      
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Application/Application.nocache.js"></script>
</body>
```

- Compile OK
- Generate EAR file OK ( War and JAR module )
- Deploy on WildfLY 10 OK
- Run on browser OK
- Degub on Classic Dev Mode (FAIL!!!)
- Degub on SuperDevMode (OK but crash in server side for some JAAS, EJB, Hibernate, etc things)

My target is, debug on Clasic Dev Mode my project.

Why?
If I upgrade GWT Material 1.6 to 2.0-rc2 I get the next error.

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException: Exception caught: 2 exceptions caught: Exception caught: (null) @gwt.material.design.client.js.JsMaterialElement::displayEffect()([]): null; Exception caught: (null) @gwt.material.design.client.js.JsMaterialElement::displayEffect()([]): null
```

And I suspect it is due to @JsType annotations

Any Suggestions?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsInterop can only be used with SuperDevMode, all the bytecode rewriting that'd be needed for legacy devmode hasn't been implemented (waste of time for a deprecated feature that only works in select and/or ancient browsers)

Comment: Thanks, although classic has more advantages in debugging, I am testing to use superdevmode without losing the communication with all JEE features in my server side, like security, sessions and others.

Comment: Try out the Javascript Debuggers for IDEA or Eclipse they provide similar functionality with breakpoints, variable and stack inspection in the IDE for GWT Development mode (super dev mode).